# How to get the selected date and time from bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem by getting the selected value from the embedded/inline bootstrap datetimepicker.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <div id="datetimepicker12" ></div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
                                                                                  $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
      sideBySide: true
       });
   });
  </script>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" id="datetimepicker12" /><br/>
```

There is nothing happening with my hidden input. Not getting the selected date and time to input. I want to save the value to database table. Please help me with solution. Thanks

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: bootstrap datetimepicker